# Dynamically setting anchor text from javascript click()

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor

I have an anchor in the body of my html:

```
<a id="title" class="acc" ></a>
```

Then I have the following javascript.  The anchor text is set to 'aaa' from the first statement below.  When I click on the 'list' element, I get the alert but the anchor text is not updated.  Is something wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#title').text("aaa");

        $("#list").click(function() {
            alert($(this).text());
            $('#title').text("new title");
        });
});
```

Comment: works on my machine: http://jsfiddle.net/w4WkE/

Comment: your alert isn't looking at the same element you are changing...

Comment: This should work. Your problem is elsewhere

Comment: Is it possible you have duplicate Ids? - as in two or more elements with id="title"?

Answer (score 0):

try it with .html like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var title = $('#title').html("aaa");

        $("#list").click(function() {
            alert(title.text());
            title.html('new title');
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nicer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#title').html("aaa");
});


$("#list").do("click", function() {
    alert($(this).html());
    $('#title').html("new title");
});
```